# apt-get install not working in script

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt

I create a small script that installs a set of linux paquets .

Strangely apt-get install always fails and tells me that the package have not been found.
Here is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get install xfce4 postgresql-9.0 pgadmin3 chromium-browser wine iftop
```

What can i do to fix this ?

Thanks .

Comment: Can you post the results of sudo apt-get install --simulate xfce4 postgresql-9.0 pgadmin3 chromium-browser wine iftop ?

Comment: in fact it fail at the first line :

Comment: How does it fail? I've tried apt-get --simulate install <the rest> and apt-get install --simulate <the rest> and both succeed on my machine. Can you post more info on how it is failing? Although, I have to say that both George and Shane have good points. You should try those first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line of your script. Remove the space.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Also what @Shane said: on a script you may want to use `-y` to automate the process.

**Update**
Have you run `chmod +x scriptname` before trying to run it?
Can you please post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: This is only a convention, not mandatory. Quoting Dennis Ritchie, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-bang#History "To take advantage of this wonderful opportunity,
put `#! /bin/sh` at the left margin of the first line of your shell scripts. Blanks after ! are OK."

Comment: You're right, I double checked a simple bash script and it works both with a space between `#!` and `/bin/sh` as well without one. But @isoman mentioned that his script is failing in the first line so I thought he give it a try.  We'll have to wait for his feedback.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to install something from that PPA repository, your `apt-get update` should happen after you add the repo, not before.

You'll want a `-y` on the potentially interactive steps, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issues. The real key to solving this was the error on the first line `#!/bin/sh`. I was writing my script on a Windows machine and the Ubuntu box was a VM. Some Windows line endings were messing me up. [I fixed it with `dos2unix` as referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found).

Comment: /bin/sh in Ubuntu is not necessarily Bash. Check your install's symlinks. Good odds you'll find it's set to Dash instead.

Answer (score 0):

also you should first update apt-get and then install so the script should look like

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install xfce4 postgresql-9.0 pgadmin3 chromium-browser wine iftop
```

next make the file executable

```
chmod 755 script
```

Comment: well i tried with this tiny script to isolate the problem: #!bin/bash apt-get install -y iftop . i get an error telling that it can't find the package . When i run this commmand manually it work fine .

Answer (score 0):

Start using version control for system admin scripts.  This will help highlight issues as raised by @volker238.

Especially distributed systems like Mercurial or Git will help getting the code across correctly.  Both will properly convert line endings cross-platform.

Several times, when I received Copy/Paste contributions from others, the `hg log` told me exactly what had changed when the shell complained about syntax errors, and nothing obvious could be seen.

And if you want to scale up further, combine this with `chef` or `puppet`, to create repeatable deployment plans for your systems.